# Redirect to another view angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm using sweetalert to display messages to the user. I want to redirect to another view after showing the messages.

My sweet messages looks like this:

```
swal({
 title: "Some",
 text: "Good for you!",
 type: "success",
 confirmButtonColor: "#3bed94",
 confirmButtonText: "Go to other view!!!!",
 closeOnConfirm: true,
 html: true
 }, function (isConfirm) {
    $location.path('/myViewToShow');
   //$window.location.path('/myViewToShow');
});
```

This message is shown when the user clicks on "save" button, inside the alert they see the "Go to other view!!" button, but it is not redirecting to the other view until it clicks again on the button "save".

Any ideas?

Comment: first does that function get called? If it does, is this being used inside a controller? If so might need to use `$apply()` assuming path is valid

Answer (score 0):

I found this function and it works ...

```
$scope.changeRoute = function (url, forceReload) {
        $scope = $scope || angular.element(document).scope();
        if (forceReload || $scope.$$phase) { // that's right TWO dollar signs: $$phase
            window.location = url;
        } else {
            $location.path(url);
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    };
```

As @charlietfl says, maybe i had to use $scope.$apply().